# How to find pdf table row count?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have generated a report with table using itext sharp. I want to check the table row is grater than one or not. My table creation is

```
 Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(570f, 600f));
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
 table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 45f,45f}
 cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", font));
 cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
 table.AddCell(cell);
 cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Age", font));
 cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
 table.AddCell(cell);
 cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Purushu", font2));
 table.AddCell(cell);
 cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("35", font2));
 table.AddCell(cell);
 doc.Add(table);
```

I have added table like this way and tried to get table roe count like

```
if(table.row.Count>0)
 {
    string data="1"
 }
 else
 {
    string data="2"
 }
```

But if the table added or not the row count shows always `'0'`. Kindly let me know the reason ? remeber it is itext sharp pdf table.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the row count like this:

```
table.Size
```

However, when I look at the table you create in the code snippet in your question, I see a table with zero completed rows. You create a table with 10 columns, but you are only adding 4 cells.

Moreover, your code should throw an exception because of this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 45f,45f}
```

You create a table with 10 columns, but define the widths of the columns as if there are only 2 columns. Either you are using a rogue version of iTextSharp (*which version are you using?*), or your code sample isn't your actual code sample, or your code should throw an error saying something like: *you define the widths for 2 columns, your table has 10 columns.*

You ask me: *the row count shows always '0'.* Kindly let me know the reason?

I think the main reason is your inaccuracy when writing code.